# Problem using ecryptfs when /home mounted in two different systems

Tags: debian, linux-mint, ecryptfs

I have three partitions on my disk:

1. Linux Mint Debian Edition (Kernel 3.11-2-amd64)
2. /home
3. Debian Testing (Kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64)

Both systems mount the /home partition, which is encrypted using ecryptfs. I have identical user names, UIDs, GIDs on both systems, and was expecting that my homedir would automagically be mounted. Here is what happens:

When shutting down 1. and booting 3. I can log in and my homedir is decrypted. However, my .ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase file changes. Its size increases from 48 bytes to 58 bytes upon login.

When shutting down 3. and booting 1. (with the updated 58-byte wrapped-passphrase file in /home) I can log in, but my homedir only contains encrypted files and I get an error message saying that my passphrase could not be unwrapped. When I re-install my old wrapped-passphrase file (the one 48 bytes long) I can log in and all files are decrypted.

In summary: booting Debian testing seems to change the wrapped-passphrase file, and Linux Mint Debian edition can't deal with this file. Need to copy back old file to decrypt my homedir.

What's going on?

Enno

Comment: What are the versions of the ecryptfs package? (`dpkg -s ecryptfs-utils`)

Comment: On system 1. it's 103-3 and on system 3. it's 103-5.